# Empty table after pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, pg-restore, unlogged-tables

I have a backup of an unlogged table called potential_users, the relation has 58677237 records in it.

Steps:

`pg_dump --format custom --verbose --file "potential_users.backup" --table "public.potential_users" productiondb`

```
pg_restore -a -t potential_users potential_users.backup
```

I see the data prompted in the terminal and when it finishes shows:

```
PostgreSQL database dump complete
```

But after a `SELECT count(*) FROM potential_users;` 0 is returned.

Answer (score -1):

Not really a solution but a workaround that worked is to restore through a csv file.

```
COPY potential_users FROM '/potential_users.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv);
```

Comment: This could be added to your question.

Answer (score -1):

Don't you need to tall pg_restore which *database* to populate?

```
pg_restore -a -t potential_users potential_users.backup   -d OTHER_DATABASE
```

From [the Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-pgrestore.html):

> If a database name is specified, pg_restore connects to that database and restores archive contents directly into the database. Otherwise, a script containing the SQL commands necessary to rebuild the database is created and written to a file ***or standard output***.

It sounds like you're seeing the latter, with the data (SQL script) appearing in the window.